# How to use VLC to display video on multiple displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I have 2 displays and would like to play the video on both without changing my windows display settings.

I have attempted to use the "Wallpaper Mode" however It does not work. I have VLC set to display the video on the second display via the wallpaper mode but all i get is the windows desktop background.

System Specifications:
Windows 7 Ultimate x64
Core i7 870
8 GB DDR3
ATI Radeon HD 4800 - 1xDVI + 1xHDMI

Comment: Your graphics card is too old for Eyefinity which leaves you to spanning your desktop. You could also look into multimonitor tools like multimon. This would allow you to have an extra button at the top of your windows and then one click to span across all monitors.

Comment: I'm not sure of an easy way to do it on windows.  On the linux side you can just get the titlebar/statusbar height and resize the window programatically to whatever size you want(eg the size of the status and title-bars bigger than the combined desktop size).  I love having access to all APIs.

Comment: Do you want to span the video over two displays or play it on two displays simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You need this video mode:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor#Span_or_extended_desktop_mode

It might involve downgrading drivers, using patched drivers, or patching them yourself with Mobility Modder to allow that mode.

Cat 11.8 is oldest for your video card.